# Android AnimationSet Sequence behaving differently depending on who i add first

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am using AnimationSet to make a sequence of animations on a dynamically created view. I use the startoffset to control who starts first. however, the animation behaves differently depending on the order on which I use AnimationSet.AddAnimation with those animations. shouldn't it not matter, and shouldn't it just refer to the startoffset?

I mean if I have a translation animation tAnimation, a scale animation sAnimation, another translate animation tAnimation2, and a rotation animation rAnimation.

and I want them to happen as follows:

1- **tAnimation** and **rAnimation** together at the beginning for a **Duration=1000 ms**
2- **sAnimation** and **tAnimation2** happen together **after** the first two animations, and last for **500 ms**

things would be like

```
AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);

//.... Animations definition
//..
//....
//...

tAnimation.setDuration(1000);
rAnimation.setDuration(1000);

sAnimation.setDuration(500);
sAnimation.setStartOffset(1000); //offsets at the duration of the first set

tAnimation2.setDuration(500);
tAnimation2.setStartOffset(1000); //offsets at the duration of the first set


//does it matter here who I add first to the animation set? 
//because if I change the order in which i add the animations to the animation set, I get different results

s.addAnimation(rAnimation);
s.addAnimation(tAnimation);
s.addAnimation(tAnimation2);
s.addAnimation(sAnimation);
```

Noting that I use a custom defined AnimationListener on the **AnimationSet** and only implemented its "AnimationEnd" handler to set the final location of the imageview i am animating after all animations are done.

and to add more info here, here's what I want to do in a picture.

I have imageviews scattered allover the screen in random positions and random rotations (I have those locations stored) - the scenario goes as follows:

1- when the user clicks on any of the Imageviews on the screen
2- the clicked imageview (object) moves to the center of the screen (center of the object is on the center of the screen) and rotates to the angle 0
3- then the clicked imageview expands to a specified scale ratio, and moves up to be exactly above the center of the screen..

get a sketch of what I am trying to do here (I am unable to post images because I am short of reputation points): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10306740/app.jpg

Comment: please dont use multiple animations of the same type (here TranslateAnimation) as its a bit tricky to get desired result

Comment: @pskink thanks for your response, but how would I be able to achieve multiple animations of the same type? - use separate sets of animations?

Comment: use a custom Interpolator

Comment: Thank you again for your response, but if I understand correctly I don't think custom interpolators would help in my case, the 2 transalations are not related - i.e animation1 go to point x,y - and animation2 go to point a,b.

isn't Interpolators about how it behaves in terms of speed between the start and end points - rather than where it goes?

Comment: as you well know speed is related to distance and time:  v = s / t,  so yes, custom Interpolator can exactly do what you try to do using tricky multiple Animations, btw what tranlation do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have imageviews scattered allover the screen in random positions and random rotations (I have those locations stored) - it goes as follows:

1- when the user clicks on any of the Imageviews on the screen 2- the clicked imageview (object) moves to the center of the screen (center of the object is on the center of the screen) and rotates to the angle 0 3- then the clicked imageview expands to a specified scale ratio, and moves up to be exactly above the center of the screen..

get a sketch of the steps here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10306740/app.jpg

I edited the questions as well

Comment: hmm,  from your sketch it seems like an ideal job for my https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll give it a try - thank you very much.

Comment: btw even if you find it useless you can still see how i made letter animation in "android" demo (the second one. just click of any letter to see it in action )